# Entity Framework - failed cast string to datetime on exec stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

So, I am really new to EF, an the problem a bit complicated for me.

Here is the data returned by my stored procedure:

```
[Date]     [Name]
8/31/2012  John Doe
8/12/2011  John Meyer
```

My entity is:

```
public class UserEntity
{
   public DateTime Date {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

when I change `Date` into `string` it is working fine.

I used

```
Database.SqlQuery<UserEntity>("exec sp_name", /*params*/)
```

to get the list.

Another problem that make it more complicated: stored procedure and entity are legacy code, used in different project so it is impossible to change.

Is there any chance for me to solve the case?

Comment: If Entity is legacy and impossible to change, how did you change it from Date to string?

Comment: the legacy code might not using automatic mapping such as ORM right? but truly i have no idea how they do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to define another class to retrieve the result:

```
public class Result
{
   public string Date {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and then convert it to `UserEntity`:

```
var users = Database.SqlQuery<Result>("exec sp_name", /*params*/)
    .Select(x=> new UserEntity
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Date),
        Name = x.Name
    });
```

Comment: horay!! you solved my case easily! thanks, but will there any performance issue?

Comment: yes, this has an obvious CPU and memory hit but whether it is significant or not depends on your use case -- you'd have to measure. Most likely, it won't be significant. Also, I'm not that familiar with `Database.SqlQuery<T>` but since it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, hopefully it will perform deferred execution so the memory impact will be very small.